# Configure Denite to Open File in New Window

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Below is my configuration for `denite`. When I select a file from the denite buffer, the file is opened in the preview split window rather than a new window.

How can I configure denite to open the selected file in a new window?

```
" Denite:
nnoremap <leader>f :Denite -direction=dynamicbottom -auto-preview file_rec<CR>
nnoremap <leader>b :Denite -direction=dynamicbottom -auto-preview buffer<CR>

call denite#custom#var('file/rec', 'command', ['ag', '--follow', '-g', '--nogroup', '--nocolor', '-u', ''])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'command', ['ag'])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'default_opts', ['-i', '--vimgrep'])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'recursive_opts', [])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'pattern_opt', [])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'separator', ['--'])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'final_opts', [])
```